# Configure index.html location in Spring initializr project

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I created a Spring boot project using [Spring initializr](http://start.spring.io/).

[image]

[image]

The project structure is below. `/resources/client` is the folder I added manually.

[image]

After I ran `DemoApplication`, I hit `localhost:8080` and I saw the home page was pointed to `/resources/index.html`. I wanted to set the home page to be `/resources/client/build/index.html`, so I added something in `application.properties`:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/resources/client/build/  ### also tried /client/build/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.html.
```

However, it did not work and the home page was still pointed to `/resources/index.html`.

Also, The application is using `dispatcherServlet` but I did not find a `dispatcherServlet` file.

[image]

Is there any way I can use custom index.html location? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try to add a `HomeController` using java code as following:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "client/build/index.html";
    }
}
```

Comment: Using the full name `client/build/index.html` works. Thanks.